# 404 network error twitter search with json

Tags: json, api, search, twitter

I'm getting this error

> SyntaxError: illegal character [Break On This Error]
>
> jQuery19106301322763694621_1367656472546(�
>
> Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'
>
> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/musictechfest.json?count=5&callback=jQuery19106301322763694621_1367656472544&_=1367656472545"

In replay to this, and I don't really understand what's the problem, it worked yesterday and suddenly it's not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('doc ready!');

    var search_term = {
        q: 'musictechfest'
    };

    search(search_term);

    function search(search_form){
        //colsole.log('searching for');
        console.dir(search_term);

        $.ajax({
//              url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?' + $.param(search_term),
                url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%twitter%count=4$refresh_interval=60000',
                dataType:"jsonp",
                success: function(data){
                    console.dir(data);
                        for (item in data['results']){
                    var tweetdate = data['results'][item]['created_at'];
```

....
Am I getting limited rate? how do i check it / fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because the Twitter search API now requires authentication?

Comment: does it? how do you do that?

Comment: See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets.  Twitter is not encouraging client side search scripts and wants authentication on every request - https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api.